# Ansible error : FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: ssh, permissions, config, ansible

I'm learning to use Ansible, did the following steps correctly :

```
<1> Download
<2> Install
<3> Generated keys
<4> Copied one key to node
<5> Checked Ansible version
```

Now when I do : ansible -m ping webservers -vvvv

## I got the follow error :

```
<192.168.29.14> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: RCLPROJECT\fni
<192.168.29.14> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<192.168.29.14> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/fni/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.29.14 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436556339.1-60920993142459 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436556339.1-60920993142459 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436556339.1-60920993142459'
192.168.29.14 | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
    while connecting to 192.168.29.14:22
```

My "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg" looks like this :

```
# config file for ansible -- http://ansible.com/
# ==============================================

# nearly all parameters can be overridden in ansible-playbook 
# or with command line flags. ansible will read ANSIBLE_CONFIG,
# ansible.cfg in the current working directory, .ansible.cfg in
# the home directory or /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, whichever it
# finds first

[defaults]

# some basic default values...

inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
#library        = /usr/share/my_modules/
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 5
poll_interval  = 15
sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
transport      = smart
#remote_port    = 22
module_lang    = C

# plays will gather facts by default, which contain information about
# the remote system.
#
# smart - gather by default, but don't regather if already gathered
# implicit - gather by default, turn off with gather_facts: False
# explicit - do not gather by default, must say gather_facts: True
gathering = implicit

# additional paths to search for roles in, colon separated
#roles_path    = /etc/ansible/roles

# uncomment this to disable SSH key host checking
#host_key_checking = False

# change this for alternative sudo implementations
sudo_exe = sudo

# what flags to pass to sudo
#sudo_flags = -H

# SSH timeout
timeout = 10

# default user to use for playbooks if user is not specified
# (/usr/bin/ansible will use current user as default)
#remote_user = root

# logging is off by default unless this path is defined
# if so defined, consider logrotate
#log_path = /var/log/ansible.log

# default module name for /usr/bin/ansible
#module_name = command

# use this shell for commands executed under sudo
# you may need to change this to bin/bash in rare instances
# if sudo is constrained
#executable = /bin/sh

# if inventory variables overlap, does the higher precedence one win
# or are hash values merged together?  The default is 'replace' but
# this can also be set to 'merge'.
#hash_behaviour = replace

# list any Jinja2 extensions to enable here:
#jinja2_extensions = jinja2.ext.do,jinja2.ext.i18n

# if set, always use this private key file for authentication, same as 
# if passing --private-key to ansible or ansible-playbook
#private_key_file = /path/to/file

# format of string {{ ansible_managed }} available within Jinja2 
# templates indicates to users editing templates files will be replaced.
# replacing {file}, {host} and {uid} and strftime codes with proper values.
ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}

# by default, ansible-playbook will display "Skipping [host]" if it determines a task
# should not be run on a host.  Set this to "False" if you don't want to see these "Skipping" 
# messages. NOTE: the task header will still be shown regardless of whether or not the 
# task is skipped.
#display_skipped_hosts = True

# by default (as of 1.3), Ansible will raise errors when attempting to dereference 
# Jinja2 variables that are not set in templates or action lines. Uncomment this line
# to revert the behavior to pre-1.3.
#error_on_undefined_vars = False

# by default (as of 1.6), Ansible may display warnings based on the configuration of the
# system running ansible itself. This may include warnings about 3rd party packages or
# other conditions that should be resolved if possible.
# to disable these warnings, set the following value to False:
#system_warnings = True

# by default (as of 1.4), Ansible may display deprecation warnings for language
# features that should no longer be used and will be removed in future versions.
# to disable these warnings, set the following value to False:
#deprecation_warnings = True

# (as of 1.8), Ansible can optionally warn when usage of the shell and
# command module appear to be simplified by using a default Ansible module
# instead.  These warnings can be silenced by adjusting the following
# setting or adding warn=yes or warn=no to the end of the command line 
# parameter string.  This will for example suggest using the git module
# instead of shelling out to the git command.
# command_warnings = False


# set plugin path directories here, separate with colons
action_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/action_plugins
callback_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/callback_plugins
connection_plugins = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/connection_plugins
lookup_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/lookup_plugins
vars_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/vars_plugins
filter_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/filter_plugins

# by default callbacks are not loaded for /bin/ansible, enable this if you
# want, for example, a notification or logging callback to also apply to 
# /bin/ansible runs
#bin_ansible_callbacks = False


# don't like cows?  that's unfortunate.
# set to 1 if you don't want cowsay support or export ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1 
#nocows = 1

# don't like colors either?
# set to 1 if you don't want colors, or export ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=1
#nocolor = 1

# the CA certificate path used for validating SSL certs. This path 
# should exist on the controlling node, not the target nodes
# common locations:
# RHEL/CentOS: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
# Fedora     : /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
# Ubuntu     : /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/cacert.org.crt
#ca_file_path = 

# the http user-agent string to use when fetching urls. Some web server
# operators block the default urllib user agent as it is frequently used
# by malicious attacks/scripts, so we set it to something unique to 
# avoid issues.
#http_user_agent = ansible-agent

# if set to a persistent type (not 'memory', for example 'redis') fact values
# from previous runs in Ansible will be stored.  This may be useful when
# wanting to use, for example, IP information from one group of servers
# without having to talk to them in the same playbook run to get their
# current IP information.
fact_caching = memory


# retry files
#retry_files_enabled = False
#retry_files_save_path = ~/.ansible-retry

[privilege_escalation]
#become=True
#become_method='sudo'
#become_user='root'
#become_ask_pass=False

[paramiko_connection]

# uncomment this line to cause the paramiko connection plugin to not record new host
# keys encountered.  Increases performance on new host additions.  Setting works independently of the
# host key checking setting above.
#record_host_keys=False

# by default, Ansible requests a pseudo-terminal for commands executed under sudo. Uncomment this
# line to disable this behaviour.
#pty=False

[ssh_connection]

# ssh arguments to use
# Leaving off ControlPersist will result in poor performance, so use 
# paramiko on older platforms rather than removing it
#ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s

# The path to use for the ControlPath sockets. This defaults to
# "%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r", however on some systems with
# very long hostnames or very long path names (caused by long user names or 
# deeply nested home directories) this can exceed the character limit on
# file socket names (108 characters for most platforms). In that case, you 
# may wish to shorten the string below.
# 
# Example: 
# control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
#control_path = %(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r

# Enabling pipelining reduces the number of SSH operations required to 
# execute a module on the remote server. This can result in a significant 
# performance improvement when enabled, however when using "sudo:" you must 
# first disable 'requiretty' in /etc/sudoers
#
# By default, this option is disabled to preserve compatibility with
# sudoers configurations that have requiretty (the default on many distros).
# 
#pipelining = False

# if True, make ansible use scp if the connection type is ssh 
# (default is sftp)
#scp_if_ssh = True

[accelerate]
accelerate_port = 5099
accelerate_timeout = 30
accelerate_connect_timeout = 5.0

# The daemon timeout is measured in minutes. This time is measured
# from the last activity to the accelerate daemon.
accelerate_daemon_timeout = 30 

# If set to yes, accelerate_multi_key will allow multiple
# private keys to be uploaded to it, though each user must
# have access to the system via SSH to add a new key. The default
# is "no".
#accelerate_multi_key = yes

[selinux]
# file systems that require special treatment when dealing with security context
# the default behaviour that copies the existing context or uses the user default
# needs to be changed to use the file system dependant context.
#special_context_filesystems=nfs,vboxsf,fuse
```

I've googled the error but couldn't find any solution, I've setup WinSCP and FireSSH, and can connect and see files there, does the error mean it can't handle keyboard-interactive password verification ? How do I turn it on or off to do it automatically ?

Since I'm new, I haven't changed the above config file, could that be the issue ?

Edit :

The hosts file look like this :

```
[webservers]
192.168.29.14
```

Comment: what does your hosts.ini file look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer online : https://serverfault.com/questions/690644/what-does-localhost-failed-missing-become-password-mean-how-do-i-get-pas

It says : "The problem is related to sudo. In /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg there is a commented out setting called ask_sudo_pass which needs to be uncommented out and set to Yes. Alternatively you can set the group the user belongs to to be able to use sudo without a password, but that's a security risk in my opinion."

Answer (score 0):

If you get SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)
Set SELinux to Permissive mode on linux machine. By Default it will be in enabled mode. 
command to set SELinux in permissive mode is $setenforce 0